# pusher and rails updating a div

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pusher

When a push is recieved I want it to update a div.
I don't understand javascript that well, but this is what i've got so far.

```
#subscription

var pusher = new Pusher('<%= Pusher.key %>');
var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
channel.bind('greet', function(data) {
  $("#data.greeting").load(location.href + " #data.greeting");
 });

#trigger

<%= Pusher['test_channel'].trigger('greet', {  :greeting => "present"}) %>
```

#present is the div im trying to update in this example. the trigger works, but nothing happens on the sub end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this.

```
  channel.bind('greet', function(data) {
  $("#present").load(location.href + " #present");
  });
```

it just ignores the input from the trigger and runs that commands, works well. might be a little more work implementing in this way, but it will do.

Answer (score 1):

Are you rendering the trigger in the view, as in, in your `.erb` file?

Trying keeping the subscription code the same and then running the trigger code in your rails console, as in, just this bit:

`Pusher['test_channel'].trigger('greet', {  :greeting => "present"})`

Comment: the trigger is successfull in the console, but the sub still doesn't seem to work

Comment: What kind of logging do you see in the debug console for your app on dashboard.pusher.com?

Comment: I get Type: API message, socket is empty, Details: Channel: test_channel, Event: greet and then the contents of the message: {
  "greeting": "present"
}

Comment: Yep, so that's the trigger happening. When you load the view, are you getting any subscription message in the debug console?

Comment: yes I get a type connection and then a type subscribed for channel:test_channel

Comment: Sounds like it should be working. Have you tried putting some logging inside the `.bind` call to see if that part of the code is in fact being reached?

Comment: if I replace "$("#data.greeting").load(location.href + " #data.greeting");" with "alert(data.greeting);". then it does work, I get an alert saying present

Comment: Ah, okay, so all that's not working is the `$("#data.greeting").load(location.href + "#data.greeting");` part of the code :D

You could try this instead: `window.location.href = window.location.href + " #data.greeting";`

Comment: with that something happends atleast. but he's trying to go to "http://localhost/%20#data.greeting" whitch obviously does not work

Comment: I could make it short by just adding "window.location.href = "http://localhost/present";". whitch basicly does what I want and just ignores the input from the trigger. but this refreshes the entire page instead of just the div whitch was what I wanted. so I guess the question is still, how do you refresh a div with pusher.. :<